# How to assure thread priority over other threads in Java?

Tags: multithreading

First thing came to my mind is thread.setPriority(). However, someone said it is not guaranteed at all. So two questions, if it is not guaranteed ...

1) How can I force scheduler to guratentee the priority of one thread over the other or others
2) What is the actual practical use case for setPriority() at any point.

As for my case here, I have two threads running concurrently. Both are responsible for managing my current existing orders. One thread monitors 50 existing orders for relative more volatile markets. The other thread monitors 150 existing orders for relative less volatile markets. I want my first thread also takes the priority over the second thread.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by "guaranteeing the priority"?

Answer (score 0):

Java does not provide a way to guarantee thread priority. If you need any kind of guarantee on these behaviors you would have to use [Real time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java).
Although there might be some scenario when you might needed it, for majority of the applications, Real Time Java is not required.

Even if absolute guarantee is not required, it is generally recommended against changing the priority of threads, unless you have done a perfect performance audit before and after the change.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java

Comment: I hope this answered your question.